# ActiveRecord returns an empty association when using joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two queries. The first one returns an association with three items:

```
Order.where(aggregation_key: params[:aggregation_key])
```

While the second returns an empty association:

```
Order.joins(:tips, :line_items).where(aggregation_key: params[:aggregation_key])
```

The only difference is that the second joins two tables. What is causing the result to be an empty association?

UPDATE:

After further experimentation, I found that if I remove `:tips` from the joins clause, then it returns a full association. Unfortunately, I need to join tips for later clauses in the statement. If anyone has any idea why this might be happening, I'd be hugely grateful.

Comment: what exactly you need

Comment: Can you post the order, tips and line_items relation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord is doing an INNER JOIN, so if the orders it finds don't have related records in tips and line_items you will get an empty association back.

LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
Order.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN tips ON tips.order_id = orders.id").where(aggregation_key: params[:aggregation_key])
```

You can use ActiveRecord's include method for this:

```
Order.includes(:tips, :line_items).where(aggregation_key: params[:aggregation_key])
```

UPDATE:

Or you can do:

LEFT JOIN

```
Order.joins("LEFT JOIN tips ON tips.order_id = order.id 
             LEFT JOIN line_items ON line_items.order_id = orders.id")
     .where(aggregation_key: params[:aggregation_key])
```